# Navigate to page that is inside div tag in JQuery Mobile

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-mobile

Following are the `J Query-Mobile` single page structure containing 3 pages first page is immediate child of body tag while other two pages are grand child of body tag so when page load in `DOM` browser shows the first page now I want to link other pages with main page but they can't show and if remove the parent `div` of 2nd and 3rd page then works fine but i want to place these page into separate `div` its my app requirement is there any possible way to call these pages

```
<body>
<div data-role="page" id="mainPage">
    <div data-role="content">
        <a data-role="button">SubPage1</a>    <!--<a href="#subPage1" data-role="button">SubPage1</a> I write this but not show other page what value should href have -->
    </div>
</div>
<div>
    <div data-role="page" id="subPage1">
        <div data-role="content">
            <a href="#subPage2" data-role="button">SubPage2</a>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div data-role="page" id="subPage2">
        <div data-role="content">
            <a data-role="button">Main Page</a>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</body>
```

Comment: Which version are you using?

Comment: `JQuery 1.9.1`
`JQuery Mobile 1.3.1`

It works fine if i do not put `div` outside 2nd and 3rd page but that div is my requirement

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> **jQuery Mobile 1.2 - 1.3**

### Update

For better results, update `$.mobile.pageContainer`'s value before changing page.

```
$.mobile.pageContainer = $("#ContainerID"); /* New pageContainer */

$.mobile.changePage("#pageID"); /* New pageContainer */

$.mobile.pageContainer = $("body"); /* Default pageContainer */

$.mobile.changePage("#pageID"); /* Default pageContainer */
```

`$.mobile.UrlHistory` will be updated, so `data-rel=back` will handle `pageContainer` changes.

---

The default `pageContainer` that accommodates all pages (direct children) is `$("body")`. Any other undefined divs are excluded from `pageContainer`. However, `pageContainer` can be set to any other value, either *Globally* before initialization or anytime after initialization.

However, this will require [`$.mobile.changePage()`](http://api.jquerymobile.com/1.3/jQuery.mobile.changePage/) function to switch between different *containers*, and re-define `pageContainer` option in that function.

Give the div that wrapping other pages an `id` as it will be used in `$.mobile.changePage()` function. Bind `click` to the button you want to take you to *subpages* and change page programmatically.

```
$.mobile.changePage("#subPage1", { pageContainer: $("#subContainer") });
```

and then

```
event.preventDefault()
```

to avoid page flickering.

```
<body>
  <div data-role="page" id="mainPage">
  </div>

  <!-- container -->
  <div id="subContainer">
    <div data-role="page" id="subPage1">

    <div data-role="page" id="subPage2">
    </div>
  </div>

</body>
```

> **[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Palestinian/b4YJL/)**

Comment: I use this `event.preventDefault()` but still page flickering annoying me

Comment: In my demo I have used `e.preventDefault()`. Double check your code pls.

Comment: In your demo also flickering so i change that line with `return false` and it stops flickering but in my app it still exist.
am reviewing again my code then comment

Comment: my `url` is not updating when `view` moves from `body container` to `sub container` portion. Maybe that is problem but am not sure about that

Comment: @BluAngel I tested it on both iPhone and iPad with preventDefault only. It's not flickering. Ill try to change a bit in the code, I'll update you.

Comment: i tested your demo in `Chrome` and remove `transition: "flip"` because i don't want that then its flickering but when I write `return false` it work correctly

Comment: I implement this in my app now in browser address bar url not updated. I have some `links` with `data-rel="back"` when I clicked on these it will back to page that i load first instead of one step back

Comment: @BluAngel because you've used `return false` you prevent updating `$.mobile.UrlHistory`. I'm working on another solution right now.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/48457/discussion-between-omar-and-blu-angel)