# Navigate to page that is inside div tag in JQuery Mobile (1.4.5)

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile, navigation, riot.js

My jQm program needs to generate nested tags (via riotjs) that will contain jqm pages. This causes jqm 1.4.5 not to find the nested page(s). A solution for jqm 1.3.2 I found at [Navigate to page that is inside div tag in JQuery Mobile](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21973129/navigate-to-page-that-is-inside-div-tag-in-jquery-mobile) but for 1.4.5 I'm struggling with the code and http://api.jquerymobile.com/pagecontainer/. My multi-page set up is as follows:

```html
<div data-role="page" id="page1">
  <div data-role="header">
    <h1>Page 1</h1> 
  </div>
  <div data-role="content">
    <a href="#page2" data-role="button" class="to-body-page">Go to Page 2 - body container</a>
    <a href="#page2" data-role="button" class="to-container-page">Go to Page 2 - different container</a>
  </div>
</div>
<div data-role="page" id="page2" >
  <div data-role="header">
    <h1>Page 2 - body container</h1> 
  </div>
  <div data-role="content">
    <a href="#page1" data-role="button">Go to Page 1</a>
  </div>
</div>
<!-- container 2 -->
<decision-keys>
  <decisiontree>
    <decision>
      <div id="Container2">
        <div data-role="page" id="page2" data-theme="a">
          <div data-role="header">
            <h1>Page 2 - different Container</h1> 
          </div>
          <div data-role="content">
            <a href="#page1" data-role="button">Go to Page 1</a>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <!-- /container 2 -->
    </decision>
  </decisiontree>
</decision-keys>
```

JavaScript:

```js
// modified from http://jsfiddle.net/Palestinian/b4YJL/
$(".to-container-page").on("click", function (e) {
  /* Version jQm 1.3.2
    $.mobile.pageContainer = $("#Container2");
    $.mobile.changePage("#page2", {
        transition: "none"
    });
    */
  /* Version jQm 1.4.5 */
  $('#Container2').pagecontainer( );// ?correct
  $('#Container2').pagecontainer( 
    "change", "#page2"
  );
});
$(".to-body-page").on("click", function (e) {
    /* Version jQm 1.3.2
    $.mobile.pageContainer = $("body");
    $.mobile.changePage("#page2");
    */
  /* Version jQm 1.4.5 */
  $('body').pagecontainer();
  $('body').pagecontainer( 
    "change", "#page2"
  );
});
```

If I just use `$('#Container2').pagecontainer("change", "#page2");` jQuery reports:

> Error: cannot call methods on pagecontainer prior to initialization; attempted to call method 'change'

I created a demo, but it gets stuck going back from the nested pagecontainer to the body-pagecontainer: https://jsfiddle.net/InfiniteDao/3vnsho76/

What is the proper use of pagecontainer if it is not a direct child of `body`; I'm stuck to figure out how to use it properly in jqm 1.4.5, can you provide any help?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: In 1.4.5 you only need to redefine pagecontainer `.pagecontainer()`. http://jsfiddle.net/Palestinian/2kvvdy81/

Comment: Tanks, this helped. But having 3 pages (1 nested, 2 normal) and having in the nested container more then 2 back-links, only one back link works (https://jsfiddle.net/InfiniteDao/3y9ym5mv/). How can it be fixed, do I have to set up `.pagecontainer()` then for each link? Still somewhat confusing this `.pagecontainer()` without good tutorials :-/…

Comment: Well, jQM 1.4 doesn't support multiple containers at the moment; the code I used in the demo above is a workaround using `.pagecontainer()` method. Since you're using nested container and not a direct child of `body`, I'm afraid you'd have to find a different workaround. Why don't try appending that page into `body` before navigation and then removing it after navigating to a different page? you can hide it from browser's history using `changeHash: false`.

Comment: Ah yes, appending it to `body` will work, thanks. So the jQuery slogan _The Write Less, Do More, JavaScript Library._ does not work out yet that nicely in that case by writing workarounds ;-)

Comment: True. It's perfect for small and static webpages. There are more powerful frameworks like ionic. JQM requires a lot of workaround unfortunately.